# Laravel - Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**I have an error:**

> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:
> xampp\htdocs\klikdesaku\resources\views\admin\posts\create.blade.php)"

I had used it without laravel collective form (i don't know its name)

example: `{{!!  Form::select() !!}}`

**This is my code:**

**create.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($categories as $category )
   <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function create(){
        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $categories = Category::pluck('name','id')->all();
        return view ('admin.posts.create', ['categories'=>$categories]);
    }

public function store(){
        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
            'body'=>'required',
            'category_id'=> 'required'
        ]);
        if(request('post_image')){
            $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
        }
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
        session()->flash('post-create-message', 'Post was Created ' . $inputs['title']);
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
```

Comment: I think removing ->all() fix the issue. if it does not try @dd($categories) in your view. it will show you structure of $categories

Comment: `Form:select` requires at least two arguments and if you pass those arguments you won't need to loop in order to generate the options

Comment: removing `->all()` didn't work either.... i try using `@dd($categories)`, but it only display title and category in simple form..

Comment: @apokryfos: i didn't use `Form:select` but i use `<select><option><\option><\select>`... if  i want to make Create Post using dropdown (category database).. in the PostController, what am i doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `pluck` you are pulling a column, 'name', then indexing that value by a key, in this case 'id' (the second argument). When calling `all` on the Collection returned you get the underlying associative array. So your 'id' field is the key and the category 'name' is the value:

```
@foreach ($categories as $id => $name)
   <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Even if you didn't call `all` and you have the Collection from `pluck` this would still work fine.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Database - Query Builder - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `all`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all)

Comment: thanks for your help.. it works and save to database

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function create(){

        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $categories = Category::all(['name','id']);
        return view ('admin.posts.create')->with(['categories'=>$categories])
        
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how your solution solves the problem.